# How can I check if a node has a label?

Tags: memgraphdb

I didn't fid a way how to check if a node has a label. I've found the documentation for `HasLabel` but this is related to graph output and visualization (https://memgraph.com/docs/data-visualization/graph-style-script/built-in-elements#haslabelnode-label). I need it for my Cypher query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [label.exists](https://memgraph.com/docs/advanced-algorithms/available-algorithms/label#exists) function.

Query will look like:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE label.exists(n, "Person") RETURN n;
```